# Cannot substract from given date using french date format

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why does this return `NaN/NaN/0NaN` ? I expect it to return `23/04/2018`

```js
var now = moment("23/04/2019").subtract(1, 'year').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6uokm09L/

Comment: In case you ever encounter a similar error: Logging just the `moment()` shows that the date is invalid: http://jsfiddle.net/6gmeboak/ (Not my downvote though.)

Comment: @Ivar no problem about the downvote, I'm sure my question might help others in the future nonetheless. About your comment, I did log the function but I wasn't able to link it to it being the wrong format, as I thought the `.format()` I wrote did just that. Thanks for your time! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the french format (`DD/MM/YYYY`) is not recognized by momentjs. You have to specify that format in the constructor by adding a second parameter:

```js
var now = moment("23/04/2019", 'DD/MM/YYYY').subtract(1, 'year').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this format YYYY/MM/DD the following will get to subtract year from the given date

```
var now =moment("2019/04/23").subtract(1,'y').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
console.log(now);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but you changed everything I was looking to get, so that's not really helpful.